# Angular method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

As a beginner, I facing a problem with Angular and Observables. I have API for getting information about one specific restaurant in the database, but I have to get it with a POST request. I successfully get `restaurantID` from auth.service and another API when the restaurant is logged in, But when I tried to log restaurant in console, I get `undefined`. Uniformly I don't have permission to show API here. The code:

restaurant.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Restaurant } from '../models/Restaurant';
import { LoggedRestaurant } from '../models/LoggedRestaurant';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestaurantService {

  private restaurantUrl = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';

  public restaurant: Restaurant;
  public loggedRestaurant: LoggedRestaurant
  public restaurantID;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getRestaurant(): Observable<LoggedRestaurant> {
    return this.http.post<LoggedRestaurant>(this.restaurantUrl, this.restaurantID);
  }
}
```

informacije.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { RestaurantService } from '../services/restaurant.service';
import { Restaurant } from '../models/Restaurant';
import { LoggedRestaurant } from '../models/LoggedRestaurant';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-informacije',
  templateUrl: './informacije.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./informacije.component.scss']
})
export class InformacijeComponent implements OnInit {
  restaurant: Restaurant;
  loggedRestaurant: LoggedRestaurant;
  restaurantID;

  constructor(private restaurantService: RestaurantService, private authService: AuthService ) { }

  getRestaurant() {
    return this.restaurantService.getRestaurant()

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.restaurant = this.authService.currRestaurant[0];
    console.log(this.restaurant)
    console.log(this.loggedRestaurant)

    this.restaurantID = this.restaurant.id;
    console.log(this.restaurantID)
    this.restaurantService.restaurantID =this.restaurantID;

  }
}
```

Comment: Observables need to be subscribed to in order to make a request, and they're asynchronous, meaning that even when subscribed to, you won't have the correct logs. Before using a library, I highly suggest you [read the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/observables) : we're here to help in case of issues, but this isn't an issue, that's just you not learning the basics of the framework you're about to use (no offense)

Comment: You are never calling your `getRestaurant()` function in `InformacijeComponent`.

Comment: @trichetriche, you are correct, I have to learn more about rxjs, I know. uniformly, but I get this project to work on at the same time as I learning angular. thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

httpClient.post() returns an [observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables) (RXJS). So you need to subscribe to that. Otherwise, you may use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

in your html, you can try this,

```
<span>{{getRestaurant() | aync}}</span>
```

**OR**,

you can declare a variable in your ts like **data**, and,

```
this.restaurantService.getRestaurant().subscribe(payload => {
  this.data = payload;
})
```

and in your html, you can add,

```
<span *ngIf="data">{{data}}</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I already tried
```
  getRestaurant() {
    return this.restaurantService.getRestaurant().subscribe(data => {
      this.loggedRestaurant = data
    })
  }
```
but it still returns ```undefined```

Comment: You are still returning an observable. Do exactly what i suggest.

Comment: I did that too, sorry if I spam you with this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to your API call.
In `informacije.component.ts`

```js
getRestaurant() {
    return this.restaurantService.getRestaurant()
    .subscribe(data => this.restaurant = data);
  }
```

This will asign the value returned by your service to your `restaurant` field in an asynchronous fashion.

Answer (score 0):

In `ngOnInit()` call `getRestaurant` as follows

```
async ngOnInit() {
  let restaurant = await this.getRestaurant().toPromise();
  ...
}
```